# Как пишется "бок (?) о бок"?

Tags: орфография

Как правильно писать "бок о бок": раздельно или через дефис?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Наречие " бок о бок" пишется раздельно. Наречия, состоящие из повторяющихся существительных, разделенных предлогом, пишутся раздельно.
Пример: *глаза в глаза, дурак дураком, с глазу на глаз*.

Answer (score 1):

*Бок о бок* пишется раздельно. Не путать с наречием *точь-в-точь*.